# Unable to change inner HTML of a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, innerhtml

I am very new to AngularJS. I am facing difficulty in changing the inner HTML of a `table`. I am storing a string in a variable, the string include `3` types of tags `strong` tag this works well and two tags `tr` and `td` when I replace the inner value of table with JavaScript variable then it does not convert the `tr` and `td` tags into the DOM elements.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('personCtrl',  function($scope,$http) 
{    
   $scope.fun = function() 
   {
      varible="<tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td><td><strong>ahmed</strong></td><td><strong>45kg</strong></td></tr>";
      $scope.bind=varible;
   };
});
```

Here is my HTML Code

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
     <table  ng-bind-html="bind">
     </table>
     <button ng-click="fun()">check</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I ain't no AngularJS user but I'm pretty sure that's `not` how you're supposed to work with it. It doesn't look like MVC.. where's the handlebars ( mustaches ), where's the data.. did you try following any tutorials ? I bet nothing like that was in any of them. Please go through some

Comment: Actually i tried a lot but i didn't found the solution any where it converting each and every tag into html element except `td` and 'tr'. Even i tried to adjust the code in to given tutorials but it's still not working. it doesn't converts these tags... don't know why?

Comment: This is not angular way of doing. Why not use `ng-show` here? When you click on the button show the HTML content.

Comment: No no.. what I'm saying is that while I never used Angular ( using more simple frameworks ) there is a need of three things. MVC :: `Model` being arrays of data, variables, constants etc which are being used in the `View` ( being the mustache-like templates that Angular uses as well as other libraries / frameworks for live data binding ) which theirselves are controlled by the `Controller` in order to parse, fetch, change the result ( view ) as you need it. Please have a look onto MVC pattern so you can get a general idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to trust that string as html otherwise Angular won't use them because unsafe:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxwmvs59/)

```
app.controller('dummy',  function($scope,$sce) 
{    
   $scope.fun = function() 
   {
      varible="<tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td><td><strong>ahmed</strong></td><td><strong>45kg</strong></td></tr>";
      $scope.bind = $sce.trustAsHtml(varible);
   };
});
```

It should be better to use a directive, this is a really simple example:

[Directive JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0heka6p9/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
  <table><custom-table ng-show="bind"></custom-table></table>
  <button ng-click="bind=true">check</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('customTable',
    function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: '<tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td><td><strong>ahmed</strong></td><td><strong>45kg</strong></td></tr>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                //If you need do something here
            }
        };
});
```

Comment: Why encouraging him to do non-mvc stuff in a very `mvc-oriented` framework ?

Comment: Oh well, I just answer the specific question, I don't want to express personal opinion. I know that's not the best way to do that but he isn't asking that because wants to know why his code doesn't work and I told him why.

Comment: Kindly tell me if there is another way to do this more efficiently. Or just post the link so that i can visit it. It will increase my knowledge about angular. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When *manipulating* the DOM by adding elements to it or anything, try using an [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Directives have a special property called `link` that allows you to **interact** with the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

This should be used **whenever possible**.

Also, to do things like this, look into [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) & [two-way Data Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) in Angular.

Angular shines here, so get to know it a *bit* more.